# Migrating Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have silverlight application which has same code base for both windows and web. So same code runs on windows and in browser via silverlight browser plugin. Some of the business logic is in the ViewModel.

Microsoft will not support silverlight hence we wanted to have future strategy for this application. we want to know what silverlight alternative we can use with minimum code changes that will help us.

Below are some expectation from the new alternative. ie it should

1. Have ui code base same for both web/windows
2. Reuse logic in the ViewModels.

I heard using html5 as alternative , please advise about using html5 in this case or any other stuff which we can use.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight was a great way to share code between Windows and Web. First, I would ask why you are trying to maintain two different applications. Have you considered unifying them both into a web-based application?

HTML 5 with a .NET backend is generally going to be your best cross-platform method since you already have your back-end code written. By maintaining a single platform, you won't have to double any of your work. This will fulfill both requirement #1 and #2.

I know it's a paradigm shift from your existing code base, but I have been through this type of transition. It went fairly smoothly, and I'm glad we did it. Thanks to client libraries like Knockout.js and jQuery, it's easier than ever to use an HTML 5 application to replace Silverlight.

If you still want to keep them separated, I don't know how you would achieve that goal without more work than the strategy I mentioned. As an alternative, you could continue with the application as it is in its current state. Silverlight is still a viable solution for the time-being. I would say that you have plenty of time to plan out your strategy.

Comment: we have 2 version because the desktop version does hardware interactions and runs on product dispensing system in client premise. so in this case what would be choice of tools/technology for such as system. we just want to do it with minimum rework and reuse as much as we can. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just backing away from Silverlight because you think it won't be supported. Be aware that Microsoft has guaranteed that [Silverlight 5 will be supported until 2021](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean45#sl5), so it's not dying anytime soon: it just won't get new versions.

If you're wanting to switch from Silverlight because you want to support platforms that don't run Silverlight, like smartphones, then ASP.NET would basically be the only way of reusing any business logic, and really you won't get much code reuse between a Windows application and a Web one, certainly not in the ui code.

So, basically: either keep Silverlight if that will meet your requirements, otherwise throwing it all out the window for a single web app, as Jason Young suggested, is probably the best option.